# How to add customer name and subscription email in transactional email template of invoice and newsletter

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail

I want to add a new newsletter and invoice email template, I did this through a Transactional email from Magento admin section.

In newsletter template I want --> subscription email

In Invoice email template --> I need the name of the customer
I tried it through

```
{{var order.getCustomerFirstName()}}
```

But I won't be able to do this.
Can any one suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The customer first name Model does not exist according to my knowledge.

You will need to use

```
{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

To get the customer name for your transactional email.